# ASP.NET MySQL Undefined Parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

Good day!

I have a code here that inserts, but never updates. There error I get is `Parameter '@id_number' must be defined`.

**My code:**

```
string query = "INSERT INTO pupil (`fname`, `lname`, `mi`) VALUES (@fn, @ln, @mi)";
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", txtAddFName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", txtAddLName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mi", txtAddMI.Text);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();

//create ID number
long lastID = com.LastInsertedId;
int length = 4;
string currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("yy");
string result = lastID.ToString().PadLeft(length, '0');
string id_number = currentYear + "-" + result ;
string updateIDNumber = "UPDATE pupil SET id_number=@id_number WHERE pupil_id=@pupil_id";
MySqlCommand IDcom = new MySqlCommand(updateIDNumber, connection);

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_number", id_number);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pupil_id", lastID);
IDcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The Insert code works, but the Update isn't. What I wanted to do is to get the last inserted ID and update it's field `id_number` with the last 2 digits of the current year + the last inserted ID with 4 leading 0's. For example if the last Inserted ID is 1, the value of `lastID` variable will be **16-0001**.

The schema by the way is this:

```
pupil_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
fname VARCHAR(50)
lname VARCHAR(50)
mi VARCHAR(50)
id_number VARCHAR(255)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong command instance:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_number", id_number);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pupil_id", lastID);
```

Instead of `com` just use `IDcom`

```
IDcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_number", id_number);
IDcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pupil_id", lastID);
```

Comment: @cableload It's okay, still give you an up :)

Comment: By the way guys, it works but I got yy-0001 instead or 16-0001

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")`without `Year`property. Consider to accept as an answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a second MySqlCommand IDcom and so you should add parameters for that.You were adding params to the older command object.

```
IDcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_number", id_number);
IDcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pupil_id", lastID);
```